# Failed to build sample robospice-sample-ormlite-content-provider Robospice

Tags: android, robospice

unable to build the project robospice-sample-ormlite-content-provider I use maven:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project robospice-sample-ormlite-content-provi
der: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.octo.android.robospice:robos
pice-sample-ormlite-content-provider:apk:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:jar:1.4.6-SNAPSHOT -> [Help
1]
```

I tried for more than 2 hours with all solutions found online with no luck. Can any one please provide the eclipse project ready and built ?

Thanks.

***EDIT 2:***
I use [Ropospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) library and trying to compile the samples projects:
https://github.com/octo-online/robospice

***EDIT1:***
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
    <artifactId>robospice-sample-ormlite-content-provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Robospice - Sample ORMLite + SpringAndroid</name>
    <description>A simple sample that demonstrates how to use the ORMLite module + ORMLite Content Provider and RoboSpice. As it is only a caching extension, we will combine it with SpringAndroid for REST requests.</description>

    <properties>
        <android.version>4.1.1.4</android.version>
        <robospice.ormlite.content.provider.version>1.4.6-SNAPSHOT</robospice.ormlite.content.provider.version>
        <robospice.spring.android.version>1.4.6-SNAPSHOT</robospice.spring.android.version>
        <ormlite.content.provider.version>1.0.2</ormlite.content.provider.version>
        <spring.android.version>1.0.1.RELEASE</spring.android.version>
        <simplexmlserializer.version>2.7</simplexmlserializer.version>
        <commons.logging.version>1.1.3</commons.logging.version>
        <android-maven-plugin.version>3.7.0</android-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>2.5</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.6</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
            <artifactId>robospice-ormlite-content-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${robospice.ormlite.content.provider.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
            <artifactId>robospice-spring-android</artifactId>
            <version>${robospice.spring.android.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${simplexmlserializer.version}</version>
            <!-- must be re-declared -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tojc.ormlite.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-content-provider-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${ormlite.content.provider.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>lint</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lewisd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ant</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- This configuration is only meant to provide compatibility for ant 
                        users -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/libs-for-ant</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- This configuration is only meant to provide compatibility for ant 
                        users -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs-for-ant</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                                    <excludeArtifactIds>xpp3,httpclient,httpcore,android,xmlParserAPIs,opengl-api</excludeArtifactIds>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can we see that pom.xml file?

Comment: @MSaudi, - yes, failed to compile because of absent libs 
**robospice-ormlite-content-provider** and
**robospice-spring-android**

Answer (score 0):

I dug around the internet for a while to find all the classes and jars that will make this work and eventually got it working.

I have uploaded my own working version of the Robospice Content Provider here: https://github.com/Winghin2517/RobospiceContentProvider

Unfortunately, I had to use older versions of jars to make it work - for example, jar for Android-OrmLiteContentProvider 1.0.4 did not work as it does not recognise the @Contract annotation (https://github.com/jakenjarvis/Android-OrmLiteContentProvider/issues/21) and therefore I had to add the 1.0.3 manually.

The folder for ormlitecontentproviderlibrary in my git repo contains Android-OrmLiteContentProvider 1.0.3.

The folder in my git repo: https://github.com/Winghin2517/RobospiceContentProvider/tree/master/libs contains the corresponding compiler jar: ormlite-content-provider-compiler-1.0.3.jar

I link all of them together in my build.gradle file for my app so that all dependencies are picked up.